# Extending JPanel in a class working with Gson

Tags: java, swing, gson

I'm trying to use the Gson program while extending JPanel, and I'm getting multiple errors. Is it possible to extend jpanel while it's initialized by Gson?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Plan extends JPanel {
    int w, h;
    private List<List<Integer>> blocks = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Hero> heroes=new ArrayList<>();
    int x, y;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.fill3DRect(10,10,10,10,true);
    }
}
```

The part I'm working with Gson is the following:

```
List<Plan> maps = new ArrayList<Plan>();
for (String mapFile : mapFiles)
        maps.add(gson.fromJson(new FileReader("jsons//map//"+mapFile+".json"), Plan.class).construct(heroes));
```

The error I get is like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve
```

How should I handle it?

Comment: can you sysout the json files? are they correctly structured?

Comment: {
  w=2,
  h=2,
  blocks=[[0,0],[0,0]],
  x=0,
  y=0
}

Comment: this is not correct format. try `{ w:2, h:2, blocks:[[0,0],[0,0]], x:0, y:0 }`

Comment: any updates? did it work?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with the JPanel, and everything to do with GSON. Break down the for loop and see how many iterations it's going through, and if there are any problem files.

Comment: If I remove the "extends JPanel" part it'll work perfectly, so I guess JPanel actually is the case.

Comment: can you post your code somewhere?